# Bootstrap-slider.js not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get bootstrap-slider.js (http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-slider/) to work but the only thing that shows up are textboxes example: http://kevinduong.net/boost/testpage.php
I'm 100% sure the css and js is pointing to the right directories.

```
 <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>

 <script>
$(function(){
$('#sl1').slider({
      formater: function(value) {
        return 'Current value: '+value;
      }
});
$('#sl2').slider({
      formater: function(value) {
        return 'Current value: '+value;
      }
});
$('#sl3').slider({
      formater: function(value) {
        return 'Current value: '+value;
      }
 });
}  );
 </script>
 </head>

 <body>
```

```
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to to reverse the order of your scripts here:

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
```

Because `Bootstrap Slider` require `Bootstrap JS` and `Bootstrap JS` require `jQuery` to works.